# How do I get today items with JPQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jpql

I need to get today's items from database (more specifically PostgreSQL) using JPQL.
I need all the items that their day is the same as today. I tried this but it is not working because the current timestamp and creation timestamp are not exactly the same due to different times. It does not return any result.

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.timestamp = current_timestamp")
```

The question is how do I only compare the day?

Comment: By "creation timestamp", do you mean the moment the row was inserted into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From today means from "00:00:00" until now?

```
select u from User u where u.timestamp > date_trunc('day', now());
```